# BackboneJS: Sorting collection of linked items

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have some trouble figuring out how to sort a BackboneJS collection containing linked items.
Is it at all possible to do efficiently? (I am thinking of making one returning the count of previous elements, but that is really inefficient)

What should the comparator be? - and is a double linked list required?

My items look like

[
{
id: 1,
name: 'name',
previousItem: 2
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'othername',
previousItem: null
}
]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I thought Backbone Collection already had sorting functionality. Maybe post some relevant code snippet so we can see what your implementation looks like now.

Comment: It has sorting functionality, but it requires a straight forward attribute to do proper sorting like sort on name alphabetically.

Comment: Why do you need to know what the previous item is? If you have the collection you should be able to find that easily without the reference. I guess you have case where you only have the model? One thing you could do is sort it first and relink them by just simple iteration. That would be an additional O(n) thought.

Comment: I am sorry about being unclear. I have the items and needs to build the collection from them.

Comment: Ok, if they are already linked. Then you basically have a linked list. So just start a loop with model = item1, then add model to the collection. Then set model to the previousItem. Keep going until you hit a null model item.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize your model's store the previousItem. In that case you need to know what the last item is. If you have it then what I said above will work.

Comment: I thought so, was just wondering if there were a smarter way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic code to build the collection. I'm assuming you are using a Backbone Model here. In the loop, you need to add your models to the front of the collection (unshift) since you only know the previous item.

The key here is knowing what the last item is though. If you don't know it, then this will not work.

```
model = frontItem;
while (model != null) {
   collection.unshift(model);
   model = model.attr('previousItem')    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a discussion about this on [github](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/41), you can also use [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator), if you want to use [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) you need underscore

```
var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Photo,
    comparator: function(item) {
        return item.get('pid');
    }
});
```

Comment: This requires a straight forward attribute to sort on, which I do not have.

In my case I've only an reference to the item that should be placed in front of the other.
Example data could be
[ { id: 1, name: 'name', previousItem: 2 }, { id: 2, name: 'othername', previousItem: null },{ id: 3, name: 'third', previousItem: 1 } ]

Proper sorting of these would be
id#2, id#1, id#3